# Ruby rails - grab param value from undecleared input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just trying to grab input value and pass it to the update_attribute. but it throws an error `"nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal"`. Basically i wanted to grab input value and subtract from the money attribute. any idea? thx

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
    <%= number_field :price %>
    <%= f.submit('Add') %>
<% end %>


def update
    @user = User.find(params[:student_id])
    val = params['price']
    @user.update_attribute(:student_money, (@user.money - val))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `number_field` to `number_field_tag`. Will it help?

Comment: Are you sure, that `@user.money` is not `nil`?